# Getting pixel position from relative position to camera

Tags: math, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am looking for a way to find the (x, y) pixel position of a point in an image taken by camera. I know the physical position of the object (distance - width, height and depth), the resolution of the image and probably the focal distance (maybe I could also get some others camera parameteres - bbut I want as less information as possible).

In case I am not clear I want a formula/algorithm/procedure to map from (width, heigh, depth) to (x_pixel_position_in_image, y_pixe_position_in_image) - to connect the physical coordates with the pixel ones.

Thank you very much.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288536/how-to-change-3d-point-to-2d-pixel-location

Comment: The "probably the focal distance" bit is actually not optional. You cannot project points into images without knowing the camera's intrinsic parameters (at least the focal length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the diagram linked below, the perspective projection of a 3d point with a camera depends on two main sources of information.

[Diagram](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/_images/pinhole_camera_model.png)

Camera Parameters (Intrinsics) and the where the camera is in a fixed world coordinate (Extrinsics). Since you want to project points in the camera coordinate system, you can assume the world coordinate is coinciding with the camera. Hence the extrinsic matrix [R|t] can be expressed as,

R = eye(3); and t = [0; 0; 0].

Therefore, all you need to know is the camera parameters (focal length and optical center location). You can read more about this [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved the problem by multiplying with the intrinsics matrix as stated in your answer.