# Projection matrix to project a point in a plane

Tags: matrix, projection, projection-matrix

[image]

How to determinate the 4x4 **S** matrix so that the P gets projected into Q, on the XZ (Y=0) plane?

Q = **S** P

Comment: That's an underdetermined problem: You can picture the camera rotating about the ray from P to Q. You need to add constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I will give the general solution for central projection from a point **L** to a plane **E** (assuming that **L** is not contained in **E**).

I will use Octave/MATLAB notation for convenience.

Let **L** be given in homogeneous coordinates

```
L=[lx ly lz 1]'
```

And **E** be given in Hessian normal form (also homogeneous coordinates)

```
E=[nx, ny, ,nz, d]'
```

where [nx, ny, nz] is the normal to the plane and d is its signed distance to the origin.

Then the matrix **S** which projects any point **P** (also in homogeneous coordinates) to the plane **E** through the center of projection **L** is

```
S=eye(4)*(L'*E)-L*E'
```

The central projection is

```
Q=S*P
```

**As an Octave/MATLAB function**

```
% A matrix S describing central projection to a plane E
% L a point in homogeneous coordinates of projective 3-space
% E a plane in homogeneous coordinates of projective 3-space
% Requirement: scalar product of L and E is non-zero (i.e. L is not contained in E)
function S = central_projection_to_plane(L, E)
    S = [
     + L(2)*E(2) + L(3)*E(3) + L(4)*E(4), - L(1)*E(2)                         , - L(1)*E(3)                         , - L(1)*E(4)                        ;
     - L(2)*E(1)                        , + L(1)*E(1) + L(3)*E(3) + L(4)*E(4) , - L(2)*E(3)                         , - L(2)*E(4)                        ;
     - L(3)*E(1)                        , - L(3)*E(2)                         , + L(1)*E(1) + L(4)*E(4) + L(2)*E(2) , - L(3)*E(4)                        ;
     - L(4)*E(1)                        , - L(4)*E(2)                         , - L(4)*E(3)                         , + L(1)*E(1) + L(2)*E(2) + L(3)*E(3)
];
end % function
```

**P.S.:** To derive this, note that the line through **L** and **P** can be written as a 4x4 Plücker matrix

```
Rx=L*P'-P*L'.
```

The intersection of the line Rx and the plane **E** is simply

```
Q=Rx*E
 =(L*P'-P*L')*E
 =(eye(4)*(L'*E)-L*E')*P
 =S*P
```

See also: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plücker_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

The ray has coordinates **r**(*t*) = **L** + *t* * (**P**-**L**). That is in component form:

```
r_x = L_x + t*(P_x-L_x)
r_y = L_y + t*(P_y-L_y)
r_z = L_z + t*(P_z-L_z)
```

Now you need to find **Q** = **r**(t) such that `r_y = 0`. That is done when `t = -L_y/(P_y-L_y)` or

```
Q_x = L_x - L_y/(P_y-L_y)*(P_x-L_x)
Q_y = 0
Q_z = L_z - L_y/(P_y-L_y)*(P_z-L_z)
```

In general, the projection plane is defined by a unit normal vector **n**=`(n_x,n_y,n_z)` and the distance of the plane to the origin *d*. A point **r**(*t*) lies on the plane if **r**(*t*)·**n**=*d* where · is the vector dot product.

The solution for point **Q** in general is

*t* = (*d* - **n**·**L**)/(**n**·(**P**-**L**))

**Q** = **L** + *t* *( **P**-**L** )

In pseudo *C* style code the above is:

```
// L : Light Source 
// P : Point to be projected
// n : Plane _unit_ normal vector
// d : Distance of plane to the origin
// returns: The point Q along the ray that intersects the plane.
Vector3 HitPlaneWithRay(Vector3 L, Vector3 P, Vector3 n, double d)
{
    double t = (d-Dot(L,n))/Dot(P-L,n);
    return L + t*(P-L);
}
// Intersect ray with floor (Normal=[0,1,0], Distance=0)
Vector3 HitFloorWithRay(Vector3 L, Vector3 P)
{
    return HitPlaneWithRay(L, P, Vector3.J, 0);
}
```

Comment: Although this is correct, the question was how to find a 4x4 matrix which performs this projection.